# Collapse and deselect TFS pending changes hierarchy

Tags: visual-studio-2010, view, tfs, hierarchical

The TFS pending changes view (VS2010) is annoying to use, especially the fact that the hierarchy view is always expanded. Further when I check in a few files, the pending changes view is refreshed and all the items are expanded and is selected. Considering there are multiple solutions in the workarea (which are functionally and logically disjoint) and at any time I could be working on multiple tracks, the auto refresh, expand and select forces me to go through each node and collapse and deselect it.

A bit of searching brought me to this [page](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/520449/window-pending-changes-does-not-remember-flat-or-hierarchical-view) where there specify a workaround to have the Hierarichal view selected by default using macros. Extending this method to resolve the above issue didn't materialize as I believe the events of node collapse and deselection are not getting recorded.

Is there any solution to this issue similar to say the VS Power Tool which provided an exceptional feature 'Collapse All', that collapses all the projects in the solution!

Comment: I don't know the answer, but the good news is, Pending Changes in VS11 is much, much better. It has a separate Included and Excluded file list.

Comment: When you're working on several logical changes (that is, you're anticipating creating multiple changesets), using either different workspaces, or shelving your changes may be a helpful.

Comment: @DaveShaw: Thanks for that info. I'll have a look at the roadmap for VS2011.

Comment: @RonaiR - I use VS11 Beta every day, and I don't think the RC is far off. It works with TFS2010 with no problems.

Answer (score 2):

Your complain is not new, many many people complained about that to MS for year, unfortunately there's no real solution.

There's no workaround for the expand/collapse issue, **but** to improve the experience when you deal with many changes in multiple solutions you can activate the "filter by solution" item to only show the pending changes of the current opened solution. It reduces the number of items, hoping things will get better for you.

[image]

As Dave Shaw said the experience was totally refactored in VS11, it's much better now.

Comment: Yes, this makes it more manageable. As for VS2011 I see they have discarded the hierarchical views with checkboxes and "Filter by Solution" features. I see this as a possible trade-off.